# Deleting list of elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code. 
Inside of `"videos_list"` element `i` have a list of elements that i get in "couple" variable. I'm trying to remove all elements who have a attribute `"ai"` different of `"list_couple"`(to test i put only one element). The problem is, when he find the element, he doesn't delete the other elements after the found element.

Example to illustrate the idea: Consider the list `("x", "r", "t", "b", "h", "p")` and the `id="t"`.

What he is doing is `("_", "_", "t", "b", "h", "p")`.

He should do `("_", "_", "t", "_", "_", "_")` or `("t")`.

Why the value of "i" is toggling between 0 and 1 after he finds the element? I see this with alert() function in the example. The problem is in "while" loop, i believe.

```
var clicked = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function( ) {

    var list_couple = new Array("2583521"),
    clicks = 1,
    videos = document.getElementById( "videos_list" ),
    couple = videos.getElementsByTagName( "a" );

    var i = 0;
    while( i < couple.length ) {
        var flag = 0;
        //alert(i);// To see the value of the i.
        for(j = 0; j < list_couple.length; j++) {
            if((couple[i].getAttribute( "ai" )) == list_couple[j]) {
                flag = 1;// Element found.
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( !flag ) {
            videos.removeChild( couple[i].parentNode );
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('btnMoreVideos').click();// Click on the button.
    clicked++;
    if(clicked >= clicks) {
        clearInterval( interval );
    }
}, 1000);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: why dont you use `Array.filter`?

Comment: what you're doing wrong is that you're doing everything at the same time. separate all this in at least 3 functions with clean names and things should clarify by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** I just recalled this problem and realized there is another issue with your code snippet (which is also present in @nicosierra's answer). As you are removing nodes the `couple` node list will update as it is a **live list**. This will cause `couple.length` to decrease and some nodes to be skipped.

I suggest you consider using `forEach` and `indexOf` if you can rely on their support for the node and array iterating. This just iterates all of the anchors in `couple` and if the element has a matching `ai` attribute then it will remove the element from the `videos` parent. It won't matter if you update the list while iterating

```
var list_couple = ["2583521"],
    videos = document.getElementById( "videos_list" ),
    couple = videos.getElementsByTagName( "a" );

Array.prototype.forEach.call(couple, function(node) {//iterate node list
    if(list_couple.indexOf(node.getAttribute( "ai" )) >= 0) {
        videos.removeChild( node.parentNode );
    }
});
```

Or you can also just iterate the nodes backwards

```
for (var i = couple.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(list_couple.indexOf(couple[i].getAttribute( "ai" )) >= 0) {
        videos.removeChild( couple[i].parentNode );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because the i++ should go outside of your for statement.

```
while( i < couple.length ) {
    var flag = 0;
    //alert(i);// To see the value of the i.
    for(j = 0; j < list_couple.length; j++) {
        if((couple[i].getAttribute( "ai" )) == list_couple[j]) {
            flag = 1;// Element found.
            //i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( !flag ) {
        videos.removeChild( couple[i].parentNode );
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, as I mentioned in my updated answer, there is a second problem as `couple.length` will change when nodes are removed